# How to add a plugin on only one Ionic platform?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the excellent [background geolocation plugin](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) on an Ionic project. Unfortunately Apple don't think my usage is valid enough so I have to work out how to add this plugin only on Android. I can't fix this at a code level because the very existence of the plugin marks my app as requiring background geolocation in info.plist.

Is there a way in Ionic (perhaps in package.json) to flag a plugin as only to be installed on one particular platform?

Comment: why not just remove background geolocation from info.plist before doing a build? seems like the quickest + easiest way without setting up any scripts or modifying any code

Comment: I could do this - however, I regularly update plugins using 'ionic state reset' so that file gets rebuilt every time and I'd have to remember to take it out of info.plist before doing a build.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe use [plugman](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html) to add plugin for specific platform:
First,install `plugman`:

```
$ npm install -g plugman
```

And then, add plugin:

```
$ plugman install --platform <ios|android|blackberry10|wp8> --project <directory> --plugin <name|url|path>
```

for your situation, `<directory>` should be `platforms/android`, so the finally installation command is:

```
$ plugman install --platform android --project platforms/android --plugin https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.git
```

More about `plugman`, refer to [cordova plugman docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html).Hope this will help, regards.