# Using an ionic native plugin only on Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I have an interesting use cases where I would like to use an ionic native plugin namely, bluetooth-serial only on one platform out of two. So I would like to use it on Android but not on iOS. Is there a way to add a dependency just to one platform ?

Comment: This Stackoverflow answer might help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923980/how-to-add-a-plugin-on-only-one-ionic-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923980/how-to-add-a-plugin-on-only-one-ionic-platform)

Comment: Thanks, I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Platform` Api to Detect platform and write your platform specific code.

in your .ts file:

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

export class YourPage implements OnInit {
    constructor(private platform: Platform){
    }
  if (this.platform.is('android')) {
     // Write your Android Specific code
  } else {
     console.log('Other Platform')
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that it will still ask for permission on iOS even thought I'm not using it in code.

Comment: That's Interesting. Have to look into it.

Comment: Check this Out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932245/5909026