# Capacitor add plugin to only 1 platform

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I would like to add the plugin `ios-swipe-back`, but unfortunatelly it’s causing issues on android.

I don’t need the plugin on android, but removing it manually from gradle recreates it whenever i want to resync

Is there a way to specify a plugin for only 1 platform ?

I saw this for cordova, but don't know if there's something similar for Capacitor

[How to add a plugin on only one Ionic platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923980/how-to-add-a-plugin-on-only-one-ionic-platform)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem with capacitor-ios-app-tracking plugin working only on ios.
If you are using capacitor 3, you can try to use includePlugins property for the specific platform (overriding global includePlugins property).

Check documentation https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

I didn't find solution for this in older versions of capacitor (v2).

Comment: Thanks, you read my mind, I actually upgraded to 3 and using capacitor-ios-app-tracking :D